# How to load highcharts dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

Basically I click on a button and a loading spinner will display and once the highchart is ready it will display. So how can i go about achieving this dynamic highcharts functionality ?

Comment: You can use chart.showLoading() for showing spinner when you are adding your chart data. You can use ajax for adding series to your charts. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/uo1r4gys/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the Data from your database using ajax and call the charts function.

```
    $("#btn").click(function(){ //function called on button click.

      $.ajax({ 
            url: "dataURL", 
            success: function(result){
                //result should be a array of json and the format of data should be similar to what Highcharts uses.

                drawChart(result); //calling highcharts function to draw chart.

            }
          });
    });



    function drawChart(data)
    {
       $('#container').highcharts({ //html body should have div with id container.
            title: {
                 text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                 x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                 text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                 x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                 categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                 title: {
                     text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                 },
                 plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                 }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                  valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                 layout: 'vertical',
                 align: 'right',
                 verticalAlign: 'middle',
                 borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: data //this is where you pass the data to create the chart.
       });
      }
    }
```

I have made a fiddle example to show this, but since i cannot load data dynamically i have created a local variable json and it is creating the chart on click of a button.

[Fiddle Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uo1r4gys/1/)